# What is the difference between futurum exactum and futurum simplex?

Tags: differences, future-tense

What is the difference between *futurum exactum* and *futurum simplex*? I have to learn both for an upcoming test, but I don't know the difference between the two. I do know the lines, but what is the difference between the two and how are they used?

Comment: Can you give examples of what *futurm exaxtum* and *futurum simplex* mean? I have never come across those terms, and I assume I know them by some other name.

Comment: This is also the terminology I was taught, and I wasn't aware this terminology was local: *futurum simplex* is amabo, *futurum exactum* is amavero

Comment: It does appear to be a [Dutch thing](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurum_exactum). *Exactus* can mean "concluded," so in that sense it is a synonym of *perfectus*.

Comment: That's possible, because I'm Dutch, but I didn't learn other terms for it then those

Comment: Using the terminology you've learned is fine. Can you add some example words to your question so it's easier to parse for those who know the forms by another name? (Side note: This came up in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) a moment ago.)

Comment: Related https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/8426/445

Comment: And no, these terms are very common; it's not just a Dutch thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Futurum Simplex* (simple future, future imperfect)

The simple future, *amābō*, is the most common future tense. It refers to something which is going to happen in the future: "I will love". In general, "will" is the best way to translate this into English.

You form the simple future in two different ways:

- In the first (*amāre*) and second (*habēre*) conjugations, you take the present stem (*amā-*, *habē-*), and add the endings *-bō*, *-bis*, *-bit*, *-bimus*, *-bitis*, *-bunt*.
- In the third (*currere*, *capere*) and fourth (*audīre*) conjugations, you take the present stem (*curr-*, *capi-*, *audi-*), and add the endings *-am*, *-ēs*, *-et*, *-ēmus*, *-ētis*, *-ent*.

### *Futurum Exactum* (*futurum perfectum*, future perfect)

The future perfect, *amāverō*, is much less common, and doesn't have a direct analogue in English. *(EDIT: Or perhaps it does. See the comments.)* It's used for something which happens in the future, but *before* something else.

English tends to use present-tense forms for this: "After I get home, I will eat dinner." In this sentence, "get home" is referring to a future event, happening before another future event (eating dinner). So in Latin it would be translated with a future perfect (*domum **redīverō***).

If you really need to make it clear in your translation, you can use "will have", but this tends to sound awkward in English: "After I **will have gotten home**, I will eat dinner." I'd never say something like that except in a translation exercise.

Fortunately, it's easy to form, without any weird exceptions that I'm aware of. Take the perfect stem (*amāv-*, *habu-*, *cucurr-*, *cēp-*, *audīv-*), then add endings based on the future tense of *esse* (*erō*, *eris*, *erit*, *erimus*, *eritis*, ***erint***).

The third person plural is the one to watch out for: since *-erunt* is already the ending for the perfect tense, the future perfect is *-erint*. All the rest are exactly like the forms of *esse*.

Comment: Future perfect is a normal part of English, at least for us non-native learners. They are teaching it in English courses.

Comment: @VladimirF Huh, really? As a native speaker I was taught in school that there were only three tenses, past, present, and future. Forms like "will have gone" weren't brought up (and still sound stilted to me). When the future perfect is taught, do they mean "will have gone", or the present form with a future perfect meaning?

Comment: "The train will have left by the time we get there." or "In five minutes I'll have been waiting for an hour."

Comment: As a native speaker, I agree with @VladimirF. Usually grammars teach three "times" (past/present/future), which each admit of different [aspects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect), such as progressive ("I am going"), perfect ("I will have gone"), and simple ("I went").

Comment: @brianpck Huh, very interesting. And much more accurate than what I learned! I didn't learn what the "progressive" was until I started studying linguistics specifically.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand in the comments, where you say 'amabo' is futurum simplex and 'amavero' is futurum exactum, what you are actually asking about is the difference between what most Latin scholars would call the future tense and the future perfect tense. The future tense (amabo, your 'futurum simplex) is simple a verb tense referring to an action that will occur - for example, amabo means 'I will love'. The future perfect tense (your 'futurum exactum') refers to an action that will have occured - i.e. amavero means "I will have loved". All you really need to know to translate them correctly is "will vs. will have". When you see the normal future verb endings (-o,-s,-t,-mus,-tis,-nt, in the first conjugation), translate as "will". When you see the future perfect endings, using the third principle verb part (-ero,-eris,-erit,-erimus,-eritis,-erint), translate as "will have". I hope this is the answer you were looking for.